# Vb 6.0 переменные

Tags: vb6

У меня вопрос, для чего нужны операторы UCase,LCase,ReDim,Trim, знак $,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Операторы Ucase, Lcase, Trim - опреаторы обработки строковых выражений.
Ucase переводит все символы в строке в верхний регистр, Lcase - в нижний, Trim отсекает от строки ведущие и концевые пробелы. Например: Trim("  Строка  ") => "Строка"
Оператор Redim переопределяет размерность массива. Так, если был объявлен массив T(5), то применив Redim T(10), получим тот же массив уже из 10 элементов с пустым содержимым. Если надо прежнее содержимое сохранить, то пишем Redim Preserve T(10)